# Running multiple SQL queries in table against dataset

Tags: sql, azure

I am trying to create a validation rules to run on dataset, but faced the problem, that I am not able to find out, how I can have just one table with SQL statements and run it on dataset, e.g. customer table, and return only accounts, where they meet conditions in queries.

Example of SQL statements:
[Table with SQL statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCids.png)

Thank you for the ideas ;)
Martin

Comment: And where is your query? please edit the question and add the query as text.

Comment: Apologies, I have e.g. query below, that I would like to run against dataset. As I have about 150+ queries to run, I don't want to use UNION as It could take a day. 

query:
"SELECT DISTINCT
remade.`KNA1_KUNNR`,
'ER1101' AS `Error_Code`, 
'Data integrity is missing (but NC hold has been released)' AS `Error_Message`,
'Warning' AS `Error_type`

FROM `REMADE$` remade

WHERE
remade.`KNA1_LIFSD` LIKE ''
AND
remade.KNA1_KATR10 NOT LIKE '%C'"